# Manual transition progress for UIViews and Pan gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, catransition

I am trying to implement some kind of movable view witch will change it's own frame according to parent view frame size and position.
The only decision i found is add an observer to superview's frame

```c
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
{
    [self.superview removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
    [newSuperview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}
```

Then i am change view's frame via delegate if superview's frame changes

```c
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"])
    {
        if([self.superview respondsToSelector:@selector(progressForMovedView:)])
        {
            CGFloat progress = [(id <MovableViewProgressProtocol>)self.superview progressForMovedView:self];
            
            self.frame = [self proposedFrameForFrame:_startFrame targetFrame:_endFrame andProgress:progress];
        }
    }
}

- (CGRect)proposedFrameForFrame:(CGRect)baseFrame targetFrame:(CGRect)targetFrame andProgress:(CGFloat)progress
{
    CGRect frame = baseFrame;
    
    frame.origin.x      += (targetFrame.origin.x - frame.origin.x) * progress;
    frame.origin.y      += (targetFrame.origin.y - frame.origin.y) * progress;
    frame.size.width    += (targetFrame.size.width - frame.size.width) * progress;
    frame.size.height   += (targetFrame.size.height - frame.size.height) * progress;
    
    return frame;
}
```

Finally it looks like at gif:

[image]

so is there any other ways to get the same effect?